# pip 10 no module named pip.req

Tags: python, pip

1. Installation of pip using get-pip.py is breaking. it says

   `Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /tmp/tmpvF6RoH/pip.zip (10.0.0)`
2. No module named pip.req

while installing a pip module

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ImportError: No module named pip.req
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Installation**

For installation using get-pip.py use the --force-reinstall flag:

```
$ python get-pip.py --force-reinstall
```

Obviously this is till they fix the problem https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5220

---

**Recommended Alternative to pip's internal commands**

Avoid putting any dependency links in your `requirements.txt` file. Instead use the method mentioned below. You can directly put the dependency links in you `setup.py` file. Some famous packages also maintain the requirements inside the `setup.py` file in the form of a list and don't have any `requirements.txt` file

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    install_requires = f.read().strip().split('\n')

setup(
    name='app_name',
    .
    .
    install_requires=install_requires,
    dependency_links=[
        'https://github.com/frappe/python-pdfkit.git#egg=pdfkit'
    ],
    cmdclass = \
    {
        'clean': CleanCommand
    }
)
```

---

**Imports from pip** **(BAD PRACTICE - DO NOT USE** as it may break anytime! **)**

It is highly recommended that you **avoid** this because, as mentioned in the pip user guide, these methods are not thread safe. Also since they're pip's private methods, they may change it anytime without any prior notice, thereby breaking your package installation!

If you have any imports from pip, such as:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

it'll break. Since these have been now moved to pip._internal as such:

```
from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
```

However effectively you'll have to use something like this for backward compatibility:

```
try: # for pip >= 10
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError: # for pip <= 9.0.3
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

---

**Important**

Now that said it's not a good practice to use the internal pip functions, due to multiple reasons as mentioned here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Comment: Do you know if there's a recommended alternative that doesn't make use of an internal api?

Comment: @JoeJ I've modified the answer accordingly, to include the recommended alternative.

Comment: This is sound advice to issues like https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7645