# Heroku Launching difficulty - ModuleNotFoundError - [python - flask]

Tags: python, heroku, pip

Trying to get my first/ practice web app onto Heroku. I'm getting the following error logged and after hours of research, still cannot figure it out. Any advice is so appreciated.

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Installing pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
File"/app/tmp/buildpacks/2fd51/vendor/pip-pop/pip-diff", line 15, in <module>
from pip.req import parse_requirements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
mount: failure.bad-requirements: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I am not understanding the actual problem. How am I missing pip.req? How can I fix?

Thank you.

Here is my requirementx.txt if necessary:

```
alembic==0.9.9
blinker==1.4
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
flask-blueprint==1.2.2
Flask-Login==0.4.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.1.1
Flask-Moment==0.6.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
gunicorn==19.7.1
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
Mako==1.0.7
MarkupSafe==1.0
PyJWT==1.6.1
python-dateutil==2.7.2
python-editor==1.0.3
six==1.11.0
SQLAlchemy==1.2.6
Werkzeug==0.14.1
WTForms==2.1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pip 10 no module named pip.req](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837301/pip-10-no-module-named-pip-req)

Answer (score 0):

As other commenters have stated: it appears to be an issue on Heroku's end, where Heroku's buildpack is incompatible with pip version 10. Currently, it does not seem there is much you can do, besides writing a custom buildpack.

As an example: this Github thread appears to show a similar issue. https://github.com/capless/warrant/issues/96

Answer (score -1):

```
import pip
requirements = parse_requirements("requirements.txt",session=pip.download.PipSession())
```