# gramex install error: import pip.req ImportError: No module named req

Tags: python, pip, installation, gramex

#### My Environment details:

- Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
- anaconda-script.py Command line client (version 1.4.0)
- pip 10.0.1

I'm getting below error while trying to install with 
`pip install -verbose gramex` or 
`pip install -e .` (from )
```

```
(gramex_34) <src_path>\\gramex>pip install -e .
 Obtaining file:///<src_path>/gramex
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "<src_path>\gramex\setup.py", line 7, in 
 <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ImportError: No module named req
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in <src_path>\gramex\
```

I could get the below ref on SoF its a usage issue with latest version of `pip`:

- [pip-git-issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5272)
- [similar-issue-thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasper-support-forum/7ZkiEVNnfRs)

Comment: the below thread has a [similar-case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49837301/pip-10-no-module-named-pip-req)

* updating line#7,8 as: 
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
    from pip._internal.download import PipSession 
seems to fix it locally

Comment: installing form source in `Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 2.2.0 (64-bit)` & `pip version 9.0.1` environment seems to work fine –

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: Since Jun 2018, this issue does not arise.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**:

Yes Joshua - this was raised [as an issue](https://code.gramener.com/cto/gramex/issues/394) but isn't fixed yet.

The workaround is to downgrade from pip 10 to pip 9 -- and then install. This is not ideal. Will try and have a fix soon.

Comment: thank you @s-anand its working fine with the latest dev branch update